# Синтаксис Visual studio С++

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Как создать в Visual Studio 2008 express переход с Form1 на Form2 ( Через button - при нажатие на кнопку - появляется другое всплывающее окно ) ?

Comment: Кто-нибудь, найдите дубликат. Было же!

Comment: @VladD вопрос был удален http://goo.gl/yzaNVx

Comment: Возможно, вам стоит начинать с C#, а не с C++/CLI.

Answer (score 1):

```
Form2^ form = gcnew Form2(this); 
form->Show();
```

Comment: Как это ? Есть ли какой нить видео контент на данную тему ?

Comment: @ДенисМатвеев какой видеоконтент? Форма - это такой же класс, как и любой другой. Если вы не знаете, как создать экземпляр класса, то почитайте любую книжку по изучению c++

Answer (score 0):

Можно поискать на youtube.
Например, начать с [этого](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YR6fxe1wa8g) курса или [этого](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-SXdzxWngPg).

По языку C++/CLI есть неплохая [статья](http://habrahabr.ru/post/111071/) или прямо книжка: C++/CLI. Язык Visual C++ для среды .NET Гордон Хогенсон.